# Cannot seperate text file lines by whitespace into vector

Tags: c++

Given the text file input:

```
s_1 s_2 1
s_3 s_4 2
s_5 s_6 3
```

I would like to have a vector that stores each string element into the vector. Please keep in mind that I've been researching other posts, but I couldn't manage to seperate by **whitespace**.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include<fstream>
using std::ifstream;
#include<vector>
using std::vector;
#include<string>
using std::string; using std::getline;
#include<sstream>
using std::stringstream; using std::ostringstream; using std::istringstream;

void read_file(const string &fname) {
    string file;
    string line;
    vector<string> temp_vec;

    file = fname;
    ifstream in_file;

    in_file.open(file);

    while(getline(in_file, line)) {
        istringstream ss(line);
        string token;
        getline(ss, token, ' ');
        temp_vec.push_back(token);
    }

    for (string ele:temp_vec) { //print the content of the vector
        cout << ele << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    read_file("text_file.txt"); //insert your file path here
}
```

My error in this code is that the following are printed:

```
s_1
s_3
s_5
```

However, I would like the vector to store each element and be:

**{s_1, s_2, 1, s_3, s_4, 2, s_5, s_6, 3}**

Comment: `getline(ss, token, ' ');` extracts one string, you need a loop or `ss >> str1 >> str2 >> str3;`.

Comment: Advice -- Don't interleave `using` clauses with `#include`.  Just list the `#include` headers first, and then the `using` clauses.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the code organization advice! I am a new C++ programmer, so I will keep that in mind.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects to meaningful states rather than using their default constructor and immediately changing the state. That is, change `ifstream in_file; in_file.open(file);` to `ifstream in_file(file);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker again, thank you for making a suggestion in improving the readability and ability of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include<fstream>
using std::ifstream;
#include<vector>
using std::vector;
#include<string>
using std::string;

void read_file(const string &fname) {
    ifstream in_file(fname);
    string token;
    vector<string> temp_vec;

    while( in_file.good() ) {
        in_file >> token;
        temp_vec.push_back(token);
    }

    for (string ele: temp_vec) { //print the content of the vector
        cout << ele << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    read_file("text_file.txt"); //insert your file path here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This made it much more clear how to seperate out the elements. Does the very last element in the text file also print out twice for you?

Comment: Nope. my output is: `$ a.exe
s_1
s_2
1
s_3
s_4
2
s_5
s_6
3
` Last element may print out twice due to excessive end-of-line symbol ('\n') in the input file. It makes last token empty, so variable `ele` doesn't change its value in the loop, thus it prints last unempty value again

Comment: Excellent, you are correct that I had an excess new line in my file.

Comment: `while( in_file.good() ) { in_file >> token; ... }` should be replaced with `while( in_file >> token ) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
getline(ss, token, ' ');
```

Extracts the line up to the space.  Then the next call to `getline` starts at the next line, totally skipping any further input on the previous line.

What you want is to extract each element of the line.  This can be accomplished by using a simple `while` loop:

```
    while (ss >> token)
        temp_vec.push_back(token);
```

Note you do not need to know how many items are separated by spaces.  Thus if you have more than 3 items per line, the loop will still work correctly without changing code.

Comment: Appreciate the input to why my getline() only printed the first element in a text file line. This worked as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
string token1, token2, token3;
while(getline(in_file, line)) {
    istringstream ss(line);
    ss >> token1 >> token2 >> token3;
    temp_vec.push_back(token1);
    temp_vec.push_back(token2);
    temp_vec.push_back(token3);
}

cout << "{";
for (auto &ele : temp_vec) { //print the content of the vector
    cout << ele;
    if (&ele != temp_vec.data() + temp_vec.size() - 1) {
        cout << ", ";
    }
}
cout << "}" << endl
```